# C++/Cli value disposed outside of function

Tags: .net, c++-cli

```
public :void foo()
{
   LPCWSTR bar = stringToLPCWSTR(gcnew String("xddd"));
   std::wcout << bar; //prints nothing
}

LPCWSTR stringToLPCWSTR(String^ s) {
    msclr::interop::marshal_context context;
    std::string ss = context.marshal_as<std::string>(s);
    std::wstring ws;
    ws.assign(ss.begin(), ss.end());
    LPCWSTR pcwstr = ws.c_str();
    std::wcout << pcwstr; //works
    return pcwstr;
}
```

I need to convert C# string to LPCWSTR hovewer assigned value dissapears outside of function. How can I make value to persist?

Comment: You are seeing the side-effect of the marshal_context destructor.  It cleans up, releasing memory for the unmanaged string.  Thus "context".  It can just as easily fail with an AVE, but you'd have to be lucky.  The code is too synthetic to give practical advise, other than that you need to keep the marshal_context alive as long as you use the string.

Comment: Persist the `std::wstring`, not the `LPCWSTR`

Answer (score 1):

**Update**: the answer is greatly simplified after comment from @ildjarn... just use `marshal_as<std::wstring>`!

```
public void foo()
{
   auto bar = marshal_as<std::wstring>(gcnew String("xddd"));
   std::wcout << bar;
}
```

Comment: This is lossy for non-ANSI data; converting to `std::string` first is unnecessary and actively harmful. Just `marshal_as<std::wstring>(s)` (no `marshal_context ` involved)